# Can SHA1 , SHA-256 , SHA-512 be broken up to run across multiple cores/threads?

Tags: multithreading, hash, sha

I'm studying the speed (time to calculate hash) of SHA1 , SHA-256 , SHA-512 over different processors

Can these hashing algorithms be broken up to run across multiple cores/threads ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're wondering about parallelizing the execution of computing a single hash (regardless of flavor 1, 256, or 512) then the answer is sadly no. That is because of the way the SHA transform function is defined. It operates on blocks of fixed size but the output of the transformation of each block is required by next so you can't run the computations in parallel.

Obviously it is possible to run multiple hashes in parallel, for different input strings, but that I assume you already knew.

If all you wanted was to generate digests for large inputs using underlying SHA transforms you could define an arbitrary scheme for segmenting the input and then generating digest blocks for each segment in parallel. Then combine those and so on..

Something like this:

```
 | ------------------ large input ---------------------------------------------|

 |    b0     |    b1    |    b2    |          |          |          |    bn    |
```

You can generate `H(b0), H(b1), .. H(bn)` in parallel.

Then, generate `H_OUT = H(H(b0) + H(b1) + .. + H(bn))` (where the `+` sign could be concatenation or a simple XOR but these would very likely **not** be cryptographically strong).

This method will benefit from multiple cores but `H_OUT` will not be equivalent to computing  a single hash of the original large input.

Comment: Using XOR here would be very bad. A hacker could swap two blocks together, making a corrupt file with the same hash, or if a block is duplicated in the file, he could just change both blocks and still get the same hash. If you use XOR, you should do something such as H(bn xor n) instead of just H(bn),

Comment: Yep, you're absolutely right about the simple XOR not being appropriate for crypto. I've updated the answer

Comment: Even `H(bn xor n)` is vulnerable, if the blocks themselves happen to contain incrementing numbers that cancel out the counter. The bad guy could construct such a file to produce a collision, but even without a bad guy, incrementing numbers are pretty common in real world inputs.

Comment: If the input is so large that you want to parallelize the final concatenation step too, you can use a Merkle tree instead of the simpler hash list.

Comment: I am confused about this statement: _these would very likely not be cryptographically strong_ . Do you mean that XOR is not cryptographically strong, or the way of hashing in parallel would be not cryptographically strong?

Comment: @Nulik Neither. It was the use of the XOR operation. XOR is a commutativbe operation. So `H(b0) XOR H(b1)` is the same as `H(b1) XOR H(b0)` so this does not generate a signature that protects the order of the chunks. XOR in itself is not a cryptographic operation, so "XOR is not cryptographically strong" makes not much sense. It is its use in cryptoghraphic algorithm which can be cryptographically strong or not.

Comment: You could easily just SHA the concatenation of the N hashes of individual chunks:  `H(H(b0), H(b1), H(b2), ... H(bn))`  where the `,` represents string concatenation. That would be super fast (because the data volume is trivial), and AFAICT cryptographically strong.

Comment: @Leopd -- were you referring to the bit about using the XOR to combine the sub-hashes not being cryptographically strong?  I've reread that phrase and I can see how that's still unclear. What I meant to say is that doing the XOR would not be cryptographically strong because the ordering wouldn't matter and an attacker could generate collisions. I wasn't trying to say that the concatenation would not be cryptographically strong. Or did I miss something else?